# Detecting what is triggering a form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to walk through and alter someone else's code (racktables open source application)... and maybe I've been looking at it too long.
But I can't figure out why clicking on the "Edit Row" image/button in the 4th cell below trigger the form to submit.

**HTML Code**

```
          <tr>
             <td id=""><img src="?module=chrome&amp;uri=pix/tango-user-trash-16x16-gray.png" title="1 rack(s) here" height="16" width="16" border="0">
                  <form method="post" id="updateRow" name="updateRow" action="?module=redirect&amp;page=rackspace&amp;tab=editrows&amp;op=updateRow">
                     <input tabindex="1" name="row_id" value="26270" type="hidden">
                 </form>
              </td>
             <td><div id="location_name"></div></td>
             <td><div id="row_name">BLDG5:First Floor</div></td>
             <td>
                 <input tabindex="1" name="edit" class="edit" src="?module=chrome&amp;uri=pix/pencil-icon.png" id="" title="Edit row" type="image" border="0">&nbsp;
                 <input tabindex="1" style="display: none;" name="submit" class="icon" src="?module=chrome&amp;uri=pix/tango-document-save-16x16.png" title="Save changes" type="image" border="0"></td>
             <td><a href="index.php?page=row&amp;row_id=26270">Row BLDG5:First Floor</a></td>
          </tr>
```

I've added / created the edit button, as well as some jquery code to handle the edit click event.

**Jquery Code**

```
    //edit button handler   
    $(".edit").click(function(e){
            var location_id = this.id;
            var menu = $( "#location_id" ).clone();
            //locate the associated "location_name" field for the selected row & hide the column    
            var location_name=$(this).parent().siblings().children("#location_name").hide();
            var row_name = $(this).parent().siblings().children("#row_name").hide();
            //replace location_name with the new menu
            $(location_name).replaceWith(menu);
            menu.find('option').each(function(i, opt) {
                    // when the value is found, set the 'selected' attribute
                    if($(opt).attr('value') == location_id.toString()) $(opt).attr('selected', 'selected');
            });

            //change row name to input box for editing
            var input = $(document.createElement('input'));
            $(input).attr('type','text');
            //$(input).attr('name','edit_row_name');
            $(input).attr('value', $(row_name).text());

            //replace exiting row_name with this new input box. 
            $(row_name).replaceWith($(input));
            //show save button
            var save_btn = $(this).siblings(".icon").show();
    });
```

**What I've tried so Far**

When i disable / comment out the logic in PHP that creates the form, the edit button works the way i want it to.

I've been grepping the folder structure to see if there's some javascript embedded somewhere that I'm not seeing. But nothing is jumping out at me.
It's probably something really simple that I'm not seeing / recognizing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: An [`<input type="image">` control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image) is essentially a graphical submit button. So unless you cancel its default action in your click handler (`e.preventDefault()`) it is *supposed* to submit its containing form.

Comment: Are you sure `input type="image"` exists?

Comment: @nnnnnn i didn't realize that.  i thought it was only "submit" types that triggered.  wow.  i'll have to do some more reading.  thank you though!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Yes, yes it does. There was HTML before HTML5 and as much as I hate to reference this website, you should take a look at the list at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:

```
<input type='image' />
```

is also have a default action to submit the forms just like `[type="submit"]`. to prevent it you need to stop the default behavior:

```
$(".edit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // <----use this.
```